# How to assign a value of the form (my node.east) to a coordinate variable inside the argument of a tikzmath command?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, tikzmath

The *PGF & TikZ* manual for version 3.1.9a (the current version) has this to say about the `coordinate` keyword of the `math` TikZ library (p. 706):

> coordinate 〈variable〉, 〈additional variables〉;
> This keyword enables TikZ-style coordinates such as `(2cm,3pt)` or `(my node.east)` to be parsed and assigned to 〈variable〉

Could you please give me a full working example of how a coordinate variable can be assigned a value of the form `(my node.east)` inside the argument of a `\tikzmath` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to declare a coordinate variable before you can use it.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (my node) at (3,1) {Foo};
\tikzmath{
  coordinate \c;
  \c = (my node.east);
}
\draw[<-] (\c) -- ++ (35:1) node[right, align=left, at end] {
  (\c) is \\(\cx, \cy) is \\(my node.east)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]